# Crystal Reports: Display a group section always on 2 pages

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Report with only one group section on it. After the last group footer I use “New Page After” in order to start each group on a new Page. The Details section in my group depends on the data that comes from the database, so the whole group can sometime take 1 or 2 pages. Theoretically it can take more than 2 pages too. But with the current data the maximum of pages are 2. The new requirement is now to always use 2 pages for each group even if the data in the group does not require a second page. If this is the case, then the second page should be empty (at least the group part of the page).

How can I achieve this with Crystal Reports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it as:

- Split your *Group Footer*, after which you want a blank page, into two sub-sections e.g. `Group Footer a`, `Group Footer b`.
- To insert a sub-section: open *Section Expert*, select *Group Footer* and then click on *Insert* button.
- Create three *Formula Fields* named as `ffReset`, `ffIncrement` and `ffCurrent` and set their values as:
  *ffReset*:

  ```
  WhilePrintingRecords;
  numberVar counter:=0;
  ```

  *ffIncrement*:

  ```
  WhilePrintingRecords;
  numberVar counter:=counter+1;
  ```

  *ffCurrent*:

  ```
  WhilePrintingRecords;
  numbervar counter;
  ```
- Place `ffReset` in `Group Footer b` sub-section and `ffIncrement` in top level `Group Header` section
- Enable / check `New Page After` option of both of theses sub-sections (i.e. `Group Footer a` and `b`) in *Section Expert*
- Set *suppression formula* of `New Page After` for `Group Footer b` sub-section as:

  ```
  if {@ffCurrent} < 2 then true
  ```
- Ensure that `Suppress Blank Section` is **unchecked** for `Group Footer a` and `b`
- If required, to disable insert blank page at the end of the report set suppression formula in `New Page After` as `Not OnLastRecord` for `Group Footer a` sub-section only
- To repeat Group Headers on every page you may also need to enable / check `Repeat Group Header On Each Page` option in *Group Expert*